# Error with StringTokenizer Iterator Not being found

Tags: java, compiler-errors, stringtokenizer

```
data_structures/ExpressionEvaluator.java:14: incompatible types.lang.String)
found   : java.util.StringTokenizer class data_structures.ExpressionEvaluator
required: java.util.Iterator<java.lang.String>ing> st = StringTokenize
        Iterator<String> st = new StringTokenizer(s);
```

Do I have to declare Iterator somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

Look closer:

```
Iterator<String> st = new StringTokenizer(s);
```

You are declaring a variable st of type Iterator and on it you are creating a new object of type StringTokenizer.  On the official specification:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html

You can see an example of iterating a *tokenized* string.

Answer (score 0):

`StringTokenizer` class is used for string splitting and it is not being used much in these days. You can use `split` method in `String` class. Now coming to your problem, there is no `Iterator` associated with `StringTokenizer` and it make use of `Enumeration`.It looks like you are expecting an `Iterator` object out of `StringTokenizer`object which does not even compile. So either code it enumeration and use `String.split` method to split it as array. Your code should be like

StringTokenizer tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(inputString);

```
while(tokenizer.hasMoreElements()) {
   String o = (String)tokenizer.nextElement();
   ......
   .......
}
```

or alternatively

```
String[]  splitted = inputString.split(delimter);
```